# Making the domain-model of tic tac toe

Tags: c#, java, oop, uml

I am trying to make the domain model of a Tic Tac Toe game. I'll try then to go on through the various steps of the Unified Process and later implement it in some language (C# or Java).

I'd like to have some feedback if I'm going on the right path:
[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6187267/shooterpics/tictactoedm.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6187267/shooterpics/tictactoedm.jpg)

I've defined the game with two actors, `Player O` and `Player X`.

1. I'm not sure about defining both a `Tile` and a `Tile State`. Maybe I should only define a `Tile` and have the 3 possible states specialize from it?
2. I'm not sure what is best: to have both `Player O` and `Player X` be associations with `Tic Tac Toe` or have them inherit from `Player` that is associated with `Tic Tac Toe`. Following the design shown on the pic, in theory we could have a `Tic Tac Toe` concept with 2 Player O's, which wouldn't be correct. What is your opinion on this?

Also, am I missing something in the diagram? Although I can't see any other actors for Tic Tac Toe, should I have any other?

Thanks

Comment: I dont think that tiles should have coordinates (or there should be a board.. whats the use of it?).. its only 9 tiles and they never change, i would just number them from 1-9, that way its also a little easier to check for win states.
Also im not sure if I would use player at all, you can think of an alternating symbol (O or X) to put in the tile, and when you find a wining condition you  just ad +1 to the score to the current simbol counte

Comment: A Board is a container of Tiles. And a Tic Tac Toe game has a Board. It doesn't mean I'll have those same classes in the class diagram.

Comment: sry for unrelated and necroposting, what is the software you used for this diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your diagram:

1. is constituted by should be composition relation, not association
   (Tiles cannot exist on their own, the state of Board is defined by the state of its Tiles.)
2. Player O and Player X are instances of the Player class, not subclasses
   (Player 0 and Player X have same structure as Player, they have same behaviour, the difference is in identity and state - name in your diagram)

When you are talking domain model (in context of UP), you should forget about creating a software system and include only what is important for the domain of the tic tac toe game. Think of how any game is described - it has its rules (preparation, turns, game end conditions, ...), players (with identity for more games, points, owned/controlled components, roles ...) and physical components (boards, tokens, figures, cards...). If you accept those elements to be part of the domain model for games and therefore metamodel for your tic tac toe game, you should use elements, which are instances of that elements.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative class decomposition would be to replace Board and Tile with Game and Move. A game would contain a legal series of Moves, and a Move would contain the square coordinates (or some other identifier) and whether it was player O or X. This scheme holds a little more information allowing the game can be replayed and backed up.